# Namespace or something else to avoid name conflict with Kohana's Image library

Tags: php, image, namespaces, kohana

I have a custom helper whose class name, Image_Core conflicts with Kohana's Image Library ( I can use the Library anywhere except inside my helper )

Is there any other way to call the Image Library, like a namespace or something? ( well, it isn't in a namespace, as I just checked )
or will I have to rename my helper?

Thanks!

NOTE: namespaces are NOT the only solution I'm searching for, don't get stuck on them, please.
I just want to know if there's another way to solve name conflicts with Kohana. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was traditionally no namespacing in PHP which has been a major bone of contention for may developers especially in this arena.  Recently they've added support, the documentation of which can be found [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) and is available from version 5.3 upward the [FAQ](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php) serves as a good quick reference.

If you're stuck with a lower version then I'm afraid that your limited to renaming your classes and functions with a prefix so they don't interfere.

In your case (should you have 5.4+), you may find that it's up to you to namespace your helper to work around the conflict.

Comment: Thanks! in fact, I should namespace the library, not my helper, because I'm trying to reference the library from within my helper.
Anyway, we have PHP 5.2.6 so that won't be possible.
Thanks!

Comment: If you namespace the library you may get into some difficulties should you want to update to the next version of the library (or apply a  patch).  That is unless you don't plan on updating the library or the overhead is less than the that of altering your code, of course.

Comment: If you were on 5.3+, you could still namespace your helper and use Kohana's absolute namespace path ("\Image_Core" instead of "Image_Core", for instance). Nothing would break then.